# Multiline non terminated regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, regex-group

I came across a problem with regex parsing columns in ASCII tables.

Imagine an ASCII table like:

```
COL1  | COL2    | COL3
======================
ONE   | APPLE   | PIE
----------------------
TWO   | APPLE   | PIES
----------------------
THREE | PLUM-   | PIES
      | APRICOT |
```

For the first 2 entries a trivial capture regex does the deal

```
(?:(?<COL1>\w+)\s*\|\s*(?<COL2>\w+)\s*\|\s*(?<COL3>\w+)\s*)
```

However this regex captures the header, as well as it doesn't capture the 3rd line.

I can't solve following two problems :

- How to exclude the header?
- How to extend the `COL2` capture group to capture the multiline entry `PLUM-APRICOT`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmmm, don't do it with regex?

Comment: Best is to skip the first line while reading line by line, read others and split with `"\\s*\\|\\s*"`

Comment: @Aaron Better to use Bison? ;)

Comment: @calaedo a little complex, but if you're used to it sure why not. I would just have used a imperative language to split around separator lines, then around columns while handling multiples lines cases separately

Comment: @Aaron isnt there a way to parse 'vertically' in Regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and then combine the multiline by hand? isnt that a crude method of doing it?

Comment: @calaedo no, there is not. You can count columns and use multiple groups, but you'll still require so other tool to combine the groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems. (http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

I've assumed an input string like:

```
String input = ""
            + "\n" + "COL1  | COL2    | COL3"
            + "\n" + "======================"
            + "\n" + "ONE   | APPLE   | PIE "
            + "\n" + "----------------------"
            + "\n" + "TWO   | APPLE   | PIES"
            + "\n" + "----------------------"
            + "\n" + "THREE | PLUM-   | PIES"
            + "\n" + "      | APRICOT |     ";
```

To split the header and the table you can use `input.split("={2,}")`. This returns an array of strings of the header and the table.

After trimming the table you can use `table.split("-{2,}")` to get the rows of the table.

All rows can be converted to arrays of cells by using `row.split("\\|")`.

Dealing with multiline rows: Before converting the rows to cells, you can call `row.split("\n")` to split multiline rows.
When this split operations returns an array with more than one element, they should be split on pipes (`split("\\|")`) and the resulting cells should be merged.

From here its just element manipulation to get it into the format you desire.